# How to remove visual material entry underline in xamarin forms ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, material-ui

We are using the visual material entry for our project.

```
 using Xamarin.Forms.Material.IOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(CustomMaterialEntryRenderer), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]
namespace MyApp.Android
{
    public class CustomMaterialEntryRenderer : MaterialProgressBarRenderer
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

How to remove material entry underline in xamarin forms ios?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the active underline height to `0f` to achieve this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMaterialEntry), typeof(CustomMaterialEntryRenderer), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]
namespace MyApp.iOS
public class CustomMaterialEntryRenderer : MaterialEntryRenderer
{

   protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
   {
      base.OnElementChanged(e);
      if (this.Control != null)
      {
        Control.ActiveTextInputController.UnderlineHeightActive = 0f;
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It's working fine. How to change the placeholder color in ios renderer? I have changed the TintColor property, it is not changed the placeholder color in ios.

Comment: @SoftDev Didn't you try PlaceholderColor attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [custom renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) with [material visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual/material-visual) to achieve entry underline removal.
I am using the below code to apply it for all entries in the project and it is working with Xamarin Forms 4.8+

## Xamarin Android

#### Entry

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(EntryMaterialRendererAndroid), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]
namespace XFTest.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class EntryMaterialRendererAndroid : MaterialEntryRenderer
    {
        public EntryMaterialRendererAndroid(Context context) : base(context) { }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.BoxStrokeWidth = 0;
                Control.BoxStrokeWidthFocused = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Xamarin iOS

#### Entry

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(EntryMaterialRendereriOS), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]
namespace XFTest.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class EntryMaterialRendereriOS : MaterialEntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            EntryRemoveUnderLine();
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            EntryRemoveUnderLine();
        }

        protected void EntryRemoveUnderLine()
        {
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
                Control.Underline.Enabled = false;
                Control.Underline.DisabledColor = UIColor.Clear;
                Control.Underline.Color = UIColor.Clear;
                Control.Underline.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
                Control.ActiveTextInputController.UnderlineHeightActive = 0f;
                Control.PlaceholderLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            }
        }
    }
}
```